# What is Katana talking about while confronting MacLeod on holy ground?

Tags: highlander-franchise, highlander-2

In *Highlander II: The Quickening*, General Katana confronts Connor MacLeod in a chapel. After he reminds him that they can't fight because it's holy ground, he says this:

> Ashes to ashes,
>   dust to dust.
>   If you don't take it out and
>   use it, it's going to rust.

What's he talking about? To be honest, it sounds like innuendo, but that seems really odd in context (unless they're trying to make him vulgar like the Kurgan was in the first movie).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Ashes to ashes, dust to dust" is a famous part of the Catholic funeral liturgy; the general is threatening (or at least alluding to) death, as well as to the fact that they are in a church.  The second half of the quatrain, rhyming with the first, is just jeering at MacLeod's desire to have been out of the game.  Katana is suggesting that MacLeod is out of practice, having let his blade languish in his scabbard—also that MacLeod's general preference to avoid senseless violence is pathetic.  There are vague phallic implications in there as well, just to further needle MacLeod.